# Trigger and Case statement

Tags: oracle, triggers, case

1. I want to write an SQL trigger to change the rental_rate of every new film inserted into the database on the basis of the a price chart.
2. When I press ENTER the command line goes to the next line instead of ending the statement. 
   NOTE: Question 1 and 2 uses the same code.

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER trig_rental_rate

   ON film
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
   AS
     BEGIN
         INSERT INTO film
         SELECT *,
                CASE

                  WHEN (special_features = ‘Trailers’) 
              THEN rental_rate := rental_rate + 0.10;

           WHEN (special_features = ‘Commentaries’) 
              THEN rental_rate := rental_rate + 0.50;

                  WHEN (special_features = ‘Deleted Scenes’) 
              THEN rental_rate := rental_rate + 0.20;

                  WHEN (special_features = ‘Behind the Scenes’) 
              THEN rental_rate := rental_rate + 0.20;

                END
         FROM   
               Inserted
     END
   ```

Comment: As well as needing a `/` to terminate and run the command (as it's a PL/SQL block), you're missing semicolons after the final `END` and the previous statement; you should *not* have them after each `THEN` section as it's all one statement; and you can't use `*` with other fields on its own, you'd need to say `SELECT Inserted.*, CASE ...`. (And/or use an alias for the table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After END press enter. Now press '/' and press enter. Your code will be compiled now.

Comment: I think you want to type a /

Comment: Yes.You are right. I didn't notice it :P